# In Google Map marker add more than one label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While creating marker on google map I need to show a number like (1) on center of the marker image and the place name label below the marker with some space between marker and place name label. I have achieved the place name label below the marker but I am not able to find how to put number in center of the marker image. So basically I want to provide two labels on each marker. Thank you in advance.

```js
function createMarker(data, i) {
    
    if(onCountry) {
      var result = {lat: data[i].lat, lng: data[i].long};
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: result,
        map: map,
        data: data[i].name,
        icon: purpleIcon
      });
      countryArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      var result = {lat: data[i].lat, lng: data[i].long};
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: result,
        map: map,
        data: data[i].name,
        icon: {
          url: purpleIcon,
          labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(17, 52)
        },
        labelClass:"my_label",
        label: {
          text: data[i].name,
          color: '#000',
          fontSize:'12px',
          fontWeight:'normal'
        }
      });
      allMarkerArray.push(marker);
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MapLabel class from https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label to add multible labels. For the position you just modify the latLang of the marker as you wish.

```
var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
  text: placeName,
  position: latLngBelowMarker,
  map: map,
  fontSize: 20,
  align: 'right'
});
```

The one label in the center of the marker is easily archieved by adding the label to the marker without any options.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: '1',
          map: map
       });
```